# How to extract day from date in watson conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

How to extract day from date in watson conversation. The language is French.
I would like if $day=="Samedi" (in English => Saturday) or $day=="Dimanche" (in English => Sunday), the respond is "We do not work Saturday and Sunday"

Comment: How is the variable $date set? Are you using @sys-date?

Comment: yes using @sys-date

Comment: @sys-date.reformatDateTime('E') ==> it return ('E'). maybe reformatDateTime works only with the English language

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reformatDateTime('u')` to [return the day of the week index](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#date-time). Then you can check for day 6 or 7. That would be even language-independent. The documentation for [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) indicates that the parameter should be `F`, not `u` to retrieve the index. Thus, you may want to experiment.

Comment: I used @sys-date.reformatDateTime('u') and @sys-date.reformatDateTime('F') and @sys-date.reformatDateTime('E') and all of them return the letter 'u' or 'F' or 'E'

Comment: I find the solution: in json editor ==>                                                    
     {
  "context": 
{
    "date": "<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('EEEEE') ?>"
  }
}

Comment: That returns what? I would add that to the answer.

Comment: I used in json editor :
     {
  "context": {
    "date": "<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('EEEEE') ?>",
    "date_rdv": "@sys-date",
    "date_formate": "<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy') ?>"
  }
}

For example: user input = 13 Août 2018 (13 August 2018)
$date = "Lundi" (Monday)
$date_rdv = "2018-08-13"
$date_reformate = "13/08/2018"

Comment: Why not use the index? It is language-independent.